# How to config nginx for multiple domains with 301

Tags: nginx

Now I have  multiple second-level domains ( same top-level domain ) waiting for setting in nginx  and each second-level domain will redirect to (301) different website

```
Example
http://a.example.com  redirect to  http://www.test.com/test1
http://b.example.com  redirect to  http://www.test.com/test2
http://c.example.com  redirect to  http://www.test.com/test1
http://d.example.com  redirect to  http://www.test.com/test3
http://e.example.com  redirect to  http://www.test.com/test3  
...
```

Now I can create multiple config file in nginx But I want to achieve it in one nginx config file in order to easy maintenance

> Nginx Version 1.10.3

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx) might help you

Comment: You can use multiple `server` blocks or a regular expression `server_name` with a `map`, which ever is easier to maintain. But the number of config files is a personal choice.